# Git Bash broken after installing cygwin

Tags: windows, git, bash, cygwin

after installing Cygwin on my Windows machine, the Git Bash is broken. Every time I try to execute a command the following error occurs:

> sh.exe": tput: command not found

Even reinstalling Git (Bash) didnt help...

Comment: As the error says `tput` command is missing in your cygwin setup. See if you have the required packages installed. [This link](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=tput.exe) might help you find out what packages are needed

Comment: Cygwin and Git Bash (nèe msysgit) should be independent. What command are you trying to invoke, and where from?

Comment: Basically, it appears right _before_ the input for the new command... And I've already installed tput... @ak2 I thought that too. But as you see...

Comment: No, I don't see it, because you haven't explained sufficiently what you're doing.

Comment: I already had Git (Git for Windows/msysgit) installed on my machine and then I installed Cygwin. After installing Cygwin, Git Bash didnt work anymore and there were tons of `sh.exe" tput: command not found`

Comment: Does anyone know where `tput` _should_ be in a normal msygit/Git for Windows installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is now solved. There was a weird .bashrc in my documents (at `~\.bashrc`) that set `$PS1` to a new value by using colors with the help of the tput command. This does not exist in Git Bash and its not supposed to be there.

After commenting out the line where the `$PS1` was set/exported all went normal again.

The line was something like

```
export PS1="$(tput ...
```

(I dont remember it correctly.)

I dont know where it came from, maybe I accidentally copied it in there for cygwin...

Comment: Can you add a few details, like what exactly you commented?

Comment: Thank you, and +1 for this feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to **run the cygwin setup and look for the 'ncurses' package and install it**.

(As suggested in [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/828876), and considering [`tput` is part of the ncurses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tput))

[another.anon.coward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925381/another-anon-coward) suggests in the comment to use the package-grep feature of the Cygwin site, which confirms the need for ncurses installation:

[package-grep for tput](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=tput.exe).

---

However, the [OP Philipp15b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995928/philipp15b) mentions in the comment:

> Thats the problem: We're talking about **[Git for Windows (msysgit)](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit)** and as you say, it has got nothing to do with Cygwin. But for some reason installing Cygwin broke Git.

Try launching your msysgit DOS session with the **[`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/devel/git-cmd.bat)** provided with msysgit.
It organizes the `PATH`:

```
@set PATH=%git_install_root%\bin;%git_install_root%\mingw\bin;%git_install_root%\cmd;%PATH%
```

It may help making sure that msysgit isn't affected by other Cygwin commands which could be in the path.

Comment: Now the wird thing: I've already installed it... But for some reason it seems that cygwin _removed_ tput from the git installation...

Comment: @Philipp15b: just to be sure, you are talking about git under cygwin, right? Not msysgit (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit, which is "Git for Windows", and doesn't require Cygwin at all).

Comment: @Philipp15b : 'cygwin removed tput'.. are you sure? Do you know what directory tput resided in? Did your  look there? Does your PATH still include that directory (after the CyGwin install)? Good luck.

Comment: Thats the problem: We're talking about Git for Windows (msysgit) and as you say, it has got nothing to do with cygwin. _But_ for some reason installing Cygwin broke Git.

Comment: @Philipp15b: I have edited my answer to address your last point.